# Proving independence between Beta estimated and Delta in OLS

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, estimation

I know that in ordinary least squares $b$(beta estimated) and $\delta^2$(variance estimated) are independent, but how do I prove that?

Comment: Would you care to define your terms? $\delta^2$ does not seem to appear in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares

Comment: Sorry, $\delta^2$ is the estimated variance which is $$\delta^2=\frac{e'e}{n-k}$$